# Jenkins Build Confirmation

Tags: jenkins

i have some build with prarameters and one of the parameter is environment[it will show 3 drop down options].

i want to make sure that user selected correct env to deploy

is there any way in jenkins once the user selected build with parameters and then it will ask for confirmation like

```
    Are you sure you want to deploy to prod env yes or no
```

if yes it will continue build and no if shouldn't trigger build

Any idea on this approach

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The plugin [Pipeline: Input Step](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-input-step) provides such a function.

> message This parameter gives a prompt which will be shown to a human:
>
> ```
> Ready to go?
> Proceed or Abort
> If you click "Proceed" the build will proceed to the next step, if you click "Abort" the build will be aborted.
> ```

The API for the plugin can be found [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/). There are TONS OF configuration possibilities so I am sure you will find your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in jenkinsfile

node('docker') {
withMaven(jdk: 'jdk8', maven: 'maven 3.5.0') {

```
    stage('checkout') {
        // do checkout
    }

    def runRelease = true;
    try {
        // In the console logs
        // Will ask you to Proceed a release (60 sconds temporisation)
        // after 60s runRelease is evaluated to false in exception block
        timeout(time: 60, unit: 'SECONDS') {
            input 'Faire une release ?'
        }
    } catch (err) {
        runRelease = false;
        def user = err.getCauses()[0].getUser()
        if('SYSTEM' == user.toString()) { // SYSTEM means timeout.
            echo "Aborted by System (timeout)"
        } else {
            echo "Aborted by: [${user}]"
        }
    }

    if(runRelease) {
        stage('release') {
            // do the release buld
        }
    } else {
        // do other builds
    }
}
```

}